# Are cookies on Android the same as in other browsers?

Tags: android

While comparing desktop and Mobile like Android, I want to know if the browser cookies on Android are same as desktop? Or does Android support exactly same cookies as desktop browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies work the same on every modern browser.